# Using Ninject with ORMLite

Tags: ninject, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I want to use Ninject with ServiceStack ORMLite but I'm not sure how to configure it.

I have the following in my Repository:

```cs
private readonly IDbConnectionFactory _dbFactory;

public TaskRepository(IDbConnectionFactory dbFactory)
{
    _dbFactory = dbFactory;
}

public IEnumerable<Task> GetAll()
{
    using (IDbConnection _db = _dbFactory.OpenDbConnection())
    {
        return _db.Select<Task>();
    }
}
```

I'm just not sure how to register it to use my connection string. I have bound `OrmLiteConnectionFactory` to `IDbConnectionFactory` like so:

```cs
kernel.Bind<IDbConnectionFactory>().To<OrmLiteConnectionFactory>().InScope(x => x.Request);
```

I have also created a new instance of `OrmLiteConnectionFactory` in the `Configure` method in `AppHost` like so:

```cs
var ormLite = new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(
    ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"]
    .ConnectionString, SqlServerDialect.Provider);
```

But when I try to use a service I get: `ConnectionString must be set`

### Edit

Here is how I have registered `OrmLiteConnectionFactory`:

Inside `Configure` I have:

```cs
var ormLite = new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AngularApp"]
.ConnectionString, SqlServerDialect.Provider);

// Create Tables and Seed Data
CreateSeedData(ormLite);

IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();

// Register dependencies in method
RegisterDependencies(kernel);
```

`RegisterDependencies` looks like:

```cs
private void RegisterDependencies(IKernel kernel)
{
    kernel.Bind<IDbConnectionFactory>().To<OrmLiteConnectionFactory>()
                                       .InSingletonScope();
    kernel.Bind<ITaskRepository>().To<TaskRepository>();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IDbConnectionFactory is a **db connection factory** so it should be a sigleton, i.e. you want to inject the configured instance not create a new one per request, e.g:

```
kernel.Bind<IDbConnectionFactory>().ToMethod(c => 
    new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(
        ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"]
        .ConnectionString, SqlServerDialect.Provider))
    .InSingletonScope();
```

Comment: Hi, I changed it to `kernel.Bind<IDbConnectionFactory>().To<OrmLiteConnectionFactory>().InSingletonScope();` but still get the same error.

Comment: @BiffBaffBoff where have you configured it? Ninject has no idea what it should be configured with, you need to pass and register the configured instance with Ninject. I.e. register your `ormLite` instance above as a singleton. Ninject lets you do this with `Bind<..>.ToMethod(ormLite)`

Comment: Ah, I didn't know of `ToMethod` and it's use! Thanks!

Comment: @BiffBaffBoff Minor detail, and no harm to be explicit, but `ToMethod` makes `InSingletonScope()` the [Object Scope](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Object-Scopes) implicitly.